# What does int x; arr[100] mean exactly?

Tags: c, x86

I'm tasked with changing a C program to x86 asm, and this line is confusing me:

```
int x; arr[100]
```

Full program:

```
int max = 100;
int val = 0x7a;
int x, arr[100]; /*I have a feeling that it is in fact a typo, and my compiler was just being nice*/
main(){
  x = 1;/*I just got an email saying this was an error*/
  for (x = 1; x <= max; x++){
    arr[x] = val;
   }
}
```

I think it means an array, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure it's `int x; arr[100]` and not `int x, arr[100];`? In the latter case, you're declaring an array of 100 integers; the former should be a syntax error, unless this compiler assumes `int` if type in variable declaration is not specified. Even worse, in your code `arr[100]` would be interpreted as return type of main().

Comment: Looks like a bug; I'd expect to see `int x, arr[100];`, which would declare `x` as an integer and `arr` as an array of 100 integers.

Comment: Are you sure there's no semi-colon after the `arr[100]`?  It is possible to make sense of it if there is such a semi-colon.  Otherwise, I think not.

Comment: This is exactly how it's written on the assignment sheet, so if it is an error, I'm not sure

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Sorry, Didnt realize there was a tag for that

Comment: Wait, this is being put up as a homework problem as if it is proper C code in the year 2012?

Comment: It's an assembly language course, this is about "translating" it to x86

Comment: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘main’  It will compile if you put a semicolon after the arr[100]

Comment: Maybe it's my compiler fixing things up for me. I tried running it elsewhere and I got errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an array of `int`. Before C99 in certain circumstances the type could be omitted in a  declaration and then `int` was assumed. (Note that you are missing a `;` after the declaration of your array in your example).

For example:

```
const x = 10;    // valid in C89, not in C99
auto y = 10;     // valid in C89, not in C99
```

Answer (score 1):

In old-school C, variable and functions are typed as `int` by default.  This explains both the type of `arr` and why `main()` has no return type specified.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the symbols '`arr[100] main()` are not a meaningful sequence.  There'd have to be a semi-colon after `arr[100]` for that to work.

Comment: I see someone edited the OP to add the semicolon you are referring to.  I compiled the code that was in the OP when I had the chance to do so, and it worked (with GCC, no options).  If someone badly edited the OP, there may indeed be more issues afoot.

Answer (score 0):

This just looks like buggy code:

```
int max = 100;
int val = 0x7a;
// int x; arr[100]   // Syntax error
int x, arr[100];     // Declare x as a scalar int, arr as an array of 100 ints

main() {
  // x = 1;                        // Unnecessary, as the for loop initializes x
  // for (x = 1; x <= max; x++) {  // Writing to arr[100] is an error
  for (x = 0; x < max; x++) {      // Loop thru indices of arr[]
    arr[x] = val;                  // Set arr[0..99] to 0x7a
  }
}
```